# XML Parsing error at line N extra content at the end of the document

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Been struggling with this for a while now, and I'm not really sure what the issue is.   (used validation tool) The error I get is

> XML Parsing error at line 11 extra content at the end of the document.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
 </xs:schema>
  <xs:element name="Artworks" type="artworkinfo"/>
     <xs:complexType name="artworkinfo">
      <xs:sequence>

        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="media" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="created" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="display" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to fix at least these two problems:

1. You close the `xs:schema` tag on line2, before the rest of your XSD.
2. You use a self-closing `xs:element` tag on line 3 where you probably wanted it to be the parent of the `xs:complexType` element on the following line.

In general, the error is due to violating the rule that **an XML document is only allowed to have a single root element**.  No markup may follow the single root element.

Comment: Did this and it worked but now i'm getting a "attribute name is required but missing" error

Comment: Post a new question with a [mcve] illustrating the new problem.  Include the exact error copied and pasted, not paraphrased.